# Is SASS/SCSS a tool te help the dev or does the server need to have knowledge of it?

Tags: css, sass

I'm planning on learning SCSS, but not sure if it's only meant to help the dev, or that the server of the website I'm making should also have knowledge of that.

It's going from SCSS -> CSS, so the server shouldn't notice anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SASS/SCSS is a language that has features allowing the author of CSS to keep track of properties within CSS in a more organized fashion. It also allows variables and other things which are not part of the CSS language. This is done by compiling the language into plain, regular CSS.

So a program is needed to translate/compile SASS/SCSS into CSS and that's easily installed on your computer or server. Other than doing the compile, it doesn't mean anything to the server at all.

It's an aid for the developer, not the server. To the server, it's just text it serves along with the HTML, javascript and other things.

Answer (score 0):

Great choice to start learning SCSS. You can do either. You can use a server middleware to auto compile your sass when it changes, or, do it yourself with a compile tool and serve the resulting css file along with any other assets you may have.